# Show 2 PDF pages on Landscape Mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Have anyone tried this example app for showing PDF document on a UIScrollView? https://github.com/vfr/Reader/downloads

It's a great example and it works great. But, I want to **show two pages when device is in landscape mode** *(currently, app shows only one page in both portrait and landscape modes)*

I tried in my best to figure out a solution, but I failed. If anyone have done it, please give me a help. It's highly appreciated.

*(*And also, I would like greatly thankful to **github.com** for sharing this example project as open source project.* )*

Answer (score 1):

you should try Leaves 
[here](https://github.com/vian/leaves/tree/43fe78f8c67a02719634157381acaab87deae69d) you can find out the source..... enjoy..